# CSS Media Query for offset-path

Tags: html, css

[image: Please see attached mobile view where the element(space station) is shown moving out of the offset-path]CSS Media query for offset-path is not working on mobile(max-width: 480px). It works well on Desktop resolution(1280px*720px). On mobile view(280px*150px), the moving element breaks off the offset-path and continues to move along the existing offset-path as per the Desktop resolution.Not sure why its not working? Is there something which I am missing?

Here is the below code snippet:

```css
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
.obj {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  offset-rotate: auto 30deg;
  offset-path: path('m60.72977,154.26244c0,0 41.05513,-142.64096 228.95326,-126.12023c170.42622,14.98454 119.16333,457.14878 290.30674,454.03282c164.91069,-3.00249 252.53349,-444.03609 302.27815,-435.81545');
  animation: move 10s infinite linear;
  }
.path {
position: absolute;
width: 980px;
height: 500px;
}
.map {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
 @keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container, body, .map, .path {
    max-width: 280px;
    height: auto;
    }
  .path {
    max-width: 280px;
    height: 150;
    }
  .obj {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<svg class="path" width="980" height="500" viewBox="0 0 980 500" data-name="Layer 1" version="1.1">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <metadata id="svg_34">image/svg+xml</metadata>
  <metadata id="svg_117">image/svg+xml</metadata>
  <metadata id="svg_132">image/svg+xml</metadata>
  <g id="svg_134">
   <path d="m60.72977,154.26244c0,0 41.05513,-142.64096 228.95326,-126.12023c170.42622,14.98454 119.16333,457.14878 290.30674,454.03282c164.91069,-3.00249 252.53349,-444.03609 302.27815,-435.81545" id="svg_130" stroke-width="1px" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  </g>
 </g>

</svg>

<svg class="obj" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="37" height="24" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="none" d="M18 .5v6.1364" stroke-linecap="square"/><path fill="#cff" d="M15.0303 8.0717h5.9394v4.0191h-5.9394z"/><path d="M23.5152 3.3637h0c0 3.3465-2.3636 5.8565-5.5152 5.8565s-5.5151-2.51-5.5151-5.8565h0zm-1.697 6.7177v7.0844c0 3.3339-1.6364 5.8343-3.8182 5.8343s-3.8182-2.5004-3.8182-5.8343v-7.0844z" fill="#ffc"/><path fill="#000" stroke="#262626" d="M11.6364 12.0909h12.7273v2.2967H11.6364z"/><path fill="#cff" d="M.5 9.7045h11.1364v8.1818H.5z"/><g fill="none"><path d="M.5 11.75h11.1364M.5 13.7954h11.1364M.5 15.8409h11.1364"/><path d="M2.8864 9.7045v8.1818m3.1818-8.1818v8.1818M9.25 9.7045v8.1818"/></g><path fill="#cff" d="M24.3636 9.7045H35.5v8.1818H24.3636z"/><g fill="none"><path d="M24.3636 11.75H35.5m-11.1364 2.0454H35.5m-11.1364 2.0455H35.5"/><path d="M26.75 9.7045v8.1818m3.1818-8.1818v8.1818m3.1818-8.1818v8.1818"/></g></svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't change the `offset-path` inside media query so it follows old path..?

Comment: Tried that as well, but no luck. The old path and new path remains the same. Its just that the element is not scaling to the reduced offset-path in the mobile view.

Comment: Well, as a workaround, I edited the below code for the mobile resolution(280px) and this seems to work for now. However, I believe, the media query is the correct way for this solution which adapts the code as per the different resolutions, else we would have to change the code every time for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working finally.The trick is to scale down the "path" SVG element to mobile resolution(280px*150px) by changing the width and height to 280px and 150px respectively using any SVG editor and then copy the "d" attribute from this scaled element to the CSS Media query. This works pretty well.So, the CSS attribute, "offset-path" needs to be included in the CSS media query with the scaled value of "d" attribute.